# How to automate the login process for Facebook using OAuth2?

Tags: facebook, oauth-2.0

With the way Facebook handles logging in with OAuth, is it even possible to automate the login process?

Ive tried various approaches with no success and I got my Facebook account temporarily blocked at one point!

Comment: Could you describe those approached you've tried? Which ones caused you to get your account blocked?

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to automate the OAuth process for Facebook because it is designed to have human interaction. The user needs to click the 'Allow' button to grant access to your application. You cannot bypass that step.